# RAM filling when changing views

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, ram

I accidentally found a problem in my application. I am using a template MVVM. If I start switching between views RAM starts fill up and dont free up.

**Before** 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBxG7.jpg

**After 1 munute of simply views changing**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKh0t.jpg

I really dont know how find there is the problem. I will give you as much information as you need

I initialize all of views in MainWindowViewModel(it init first when app starts)

```
  private static ViewModel1 VM1;
  private static ViewModel2 VM2;

public MainWindowViewModel()
{
   VM1 = VM1?? new ViewModel1();
   VM2 = VM2?? new ViewModel2();
}
```

To get instance of any view I user this

```
  public static ViewMidel1 GetVM1()
  {
      if (VM1 == null)
          VM1 = new ViewMidel1();
      return VM1 ;
  }
```

In other view

```
ViewMidel1 vm = MainWindowViewMidel.GetVM1();
```

All views are UserControls.
When view changed all view get properties triggered.

Maybe i do something wrong?

Constructors of views calls only when programm starts.

**Diagsession**
https://gofile.io/?c=pamZlT

**UPDATE 1:**

I delete all code from all VM and its dont help. Something wrong with xaml.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcqSZ.jpg

**UPDATE 2:**
This xaml add ~15-20 mb in RAM every time I select view. Image size 108kb

```
<Ellipse Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="5,5,5,5">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Resources/Images/image.jpg"  Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

Comment: how have you determined that the issue is server side vs client side?

Comment: Can you do the memory profiling? It seems that memory is not being released (check specifically unsubscribed events)

Comment: @terrencep its desktop app

Comment: @user1672994 The number of objects in the managed heap increases with each view change. https://imgur.com/wAUrwd5 . memory profiling in process

Comment: Add diagsession